# Вычисление дроби рекурсией. Python

Tags: python

Дано действительное число x!=0. Вычислить дробь, используя рекурсивную подпрограмму:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def recurs(i,x):
    i*=2
    if i < 256:
        return x*x+i/i**x
    else:
        return x*x+i/x*x
print(recurs(int(input()),int(input()))
```

Ответ дает, но я не уверен в правильности программы. Может i не с клавиатуры

Comment: Что у вас не получилось? Тут не будут делать задание вместо вас.

Answer (score 5):

Ещё одна реализация для сравнения результатов:

```
def fraction(x, maxi=0x100):
    def recur(i):
        return x**2 + (i / recur(i << 1) if i <= maxi else 0)
    return x / recur(2)
```

Пример:

```
>>> fraction(3, 4)
0.3256704980842912
>>> fraction(10)  
0.09998001198642725
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">

def fraction(x, maxi=0x100):
    def recur(i):
        return x**2 + (i / recur(i << 1) if i <= maxi else 0)
    return x / recur(2)
    

# try your own input    
from browser import document, html
@document["mybutton"].bind("click")
def on_click(event):
    x = int(document['x'].value)
    maxi = int(document['maxi'].value)
    document <= html.P(f'fraction({x}, {maxi}) == {fraction(x, maxi)}')
</script><div><label for="x">x: <input id="x" value="10"></div><div><label for="maxi">maxi: <input id="maxi" value="256"></div><button id="mybutton">fraction(x, maxi)</button></body>
```

Для проверки можно независимо найти значение, используя [обобщённую цепную дробь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction):

[image: continued fraction]

```
def fraction(x):
    n = 9  # 2**(9 - 1) == 256
    a = [None] + [x] + [2**(i-1) for i in range(2, n + 1)]
    b = [0] + [x**2] * n

    # @cached()
    def A(n):
        return 1 if n == -1 else b[0] if n == 0 else b[n]*A(n-1) + a[n]*A(n-2)

    # @cached()
    def B(n):
        return 0 if n == -1 else 1 if n == 0 else b[n]*B(n-1) + a[n]*B(n-2)

    return A(n) / B(n)
```

Пример:

```
>>> fraction(10)
0.09998001198642727
```

Для больших значений: `fraction(x) ~ 1/x`.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">

def fraction(x):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction
    n = 9  # 2**(9 - 1) == 256
    a = [None] + [x] + [2**(i-1) for i in range(2, n + 1)]
    b = [0] + [x**2] * n

    # @cached()
    def A(n):
        return 1 if n == -1 else b[0] if n == 0 else b[n]*A(n-1) + a[n]*A(n-2)

    # @cached()
    def B(n):
        return 0 if n == -1 else 1 if n == 0 else b[n]*B(n-1) + a[n]*B(n-2)

    return A(n) / B(n)

  

# try your own input    
from browser import document, html
@document["mybutton"].bind("click")
def on_click(event):
    x = int(document['x'].value)
    document <= html.P(f'fraction({x}) == {fraction(x)}')
</script><div><label for="x">x: <input id="x" value="10000000000"></div><button id="mybutton">fraction(x)</button></body>
```

Чтобы с произвольной заданной точностью посчитать значения, можно [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) в обоих реализациях использовать:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> fraction(Decimal(10))
Decimal('0.09998001198642726105630197652')
```

[`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction) вычисления позволяет точно проводить в этом случае (`return Fraction(A(n), B(n))`):

```
print(fraction(10))
# -> 1283224212628/12834807549355
```

При использовании float, первое решение теряет точность (`...725` вместо `...727`). Но проверка с использованием `fractions.Fraction` подтверждает, что оба способа вычисления идентичны.

Answer (score 2):

```
def f(x, mx, n=2):
    if n == mx:
        return x**2 + n / x**2
    return x**2 + n / f(x, mx, n*2)

def func(x, i=256):
    return x / f(x, i, 2)
```

Проверка:

```
In [13]: 3 / ( 9 + 2 / ( 9 + 4/9) )
Out[13]: 0.3256704980842912

In [14]: func(3, 4)
Out[14]: 0.3256704980842912

In [15]: func(10, 256)
Out[15]: 0.09998001198642725
```

Comment: Что-то функций многовато