# Указать кол-во знаков после точки в строке для перевода во float

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

Есть строка вида `foo = '1240000'`. Известно, что в этой строке последние 6 цифр всегда означают цифры после точки, т.е. `1240000 = 1.240000 = 1.24`, `3000000 = 3.000000 = 3` и т.д.

Каким образом правильнее всего перевести эту строку во float?

Догадался только до такого способа:

```
foo = '1240000'
bar = float(foo[:-6] + '.' + foo[-6:])
```

Сперва делаю два среза строки и вставляю между ними точку, потом уже перевожу во float.

Comment: Похоже что такая строка нужна для точных расчетов с валютой. Во float ее переводить тогда не совсем нецелесообразно. Можно потерять точность если использовать полученный float для дальнейших рассчетов.

Comment: @coder675 Можно поподробнее? И да, это операции с валютой, не прогадали.

Comment: Ну в некоторых языках есть специальные типы данных для валюты например в VBA есть тип Currency. Ну судя по беглому взгляду на типы Python там такого нет. В данном случае точность float ограничена порядка 16 знаков после запятой. То есть технически при каждой операции может происходить погрешность +-1/10^16 от размера с оперируемым числом. Чтобы такого не случилось лучше производить расчеты через такие увеличенные целые числа, а конечный результат выводить строкой.

Comment: @coder675 всё гораздо хуже. Оперируя с float вы не просто погрешность в каком-то далёком знаке после запятой получаете, а в зависимости от конкретного алгоритма, быстро на порядки величины ошибаться можно, если специальные меры не принимать¶ Обсуждение как валюту представлять — это вообще тема для отдельного вопроса (серии вопросов)¶ Для арифметики с фиксированной точностью можно decimal модуль использовать (реализовывать самостоятельно поверх целых —это не для каждого). Для общения с внешним миром, можно в целые центы (или другую выбранную точность) превращать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код в вопросе уже правильный (сохраняет точность насколько это возможно для `float`). Другие способы могут потерять точность:

```
>>> s = '9007199254740993'
>>> float(f'{s[:-6]}.{s[-6:]}')  # ближайшее представимое как float
9007199254.740993
>>> float(s) / 1000000           # потеря точности
9007199254.740992
```

В целом, операции с `float` могут не интуитивно себя вести:

- [Отображение числа 9223372036854775807](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/690856/23044)
- [Ляп в Питоне: x + 1.0 < x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/748183/23044)

Можно использовать [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) или [`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction) для точного представления десятичной дроби (в зависимости от задачи). К примеру:

- [Найти частичную сумму знакопеременного ряда с факториалом: `sum (-1)^k (k + 1) / k!, k=0..n`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/728795/23044)
- [Вычисление дроби рекурсией. Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/788440/23044)

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = '1240000'
print (float(foo) / 1000000)
```

Смещение запятой в десятичных числах делается через деление/умножение на 10^x

Comment: Иногда удивляюсь своей глупости. Спасибо!